# Commandline executes properly but eclipse errors for java

Tags: java, eclipse

Could anyone please help me here in Eclipse? I have taken the java code to test MQ connectivity from [MQlink](http://endrasenn.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/readwrite-to-ibm-mq-sample-java-code/)

After that I added the ibm.com.mq.jar(without which the MQ classes cant be used) file after creating a lib folder under the project folder as per [includejarLink](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)/)

After that step I can see the jar in the rerefenced libraries.

However when I run this as Java application through eclipse I get the below error(used the exact same code provided in the link)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/ResourceException
    at com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.<clinit>(MQEnvironment.java:441)
    at mq.MQRead.init(MQRead.java:32)
    at mq.MQRead.main(MQRead.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Now if I compile the java file using the command line

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javac MQRead.java
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java MyClass
```

I get proper output

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'.
```

I know that some MQ error code as I have used some default values. How come eclipse is failing with the error? I have added the jar to the referenced library as well.

My eclipse version below

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Build id: 20100218-1602
```

Comment: Do you have a CLASSPATH environment variable setup, by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception clearly says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException`

So you need to add the jar file containing the above mentioned file in your classpath.

[Download from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxresourcejar.htm)

Comment: Thanks.I will try this. How come it is working fine in commandline?